# Check SVN working version is same as head before running .exe

Tags: svn, batch-file

hi I'm new to svn and I want to write a windows command line script that checks if the working version of a file is the same as the head and if it is run a exe? If it isn't the same as the working version I want to exit the script without running the executable.

Help please!

Comment: Welcome to SO Chris! You'll get a better response if you show us what you've tried and ask for help getting it working. Check out `svn status` to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know enough about Windows cmd batch processing language to know that doing things like this may be next to impossible. At least Powershell is a complete language.

I can tell you one thing: You can look at `svn status --show-updates file` to see if `file` is up to date:

File is up to date:

```
C> svn status --show-updates file
Status against revision:     182332
```

File isn't up to date:

```
C> svn st -u file
        *            file
Status against revision:     182332
```

If you can somehow use the Windows command batch language to parse the output of that command, you could check whether `file` is the latest version or not.

Comment: Thanks I coded the batch file language, I just needed to know the svn commands